# Getting android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: but working on most phones

Tags: android, android-layout, exception, android-resources

I have an active app on the playstore and recently one smartphone encountered an exception. But I actually have no clue how I can debug this as there is just a resource id given.

The resources are all there and working for 99% of other phones. Where should I start looking?

```
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070036
       at android.content.res.Resources.getValue + 1118(Resources.java:1118)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates + 4(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:4)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.addDelegate(AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.VectorEnabledTintResources.getDrawable(VectorEnabledTintResources.java)
       at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate + 173(StateListDrawable.java:173)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner + 901(Drawable.java:901)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml + 837(Drawable.java:837)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable + 2092(Resources.java:2092)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable + 601(TypedArray.java:601)
       at android.view.View.<init> + 3364(View.java:3364)
       at android.widget.ImageView.<init> + 121(ImageView.java:121)
       at android.widget.ImageButton.<init> + 87(ImageButton.java:87)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.ensureNavButtonView(Toolbar.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.setNavigationContentDescription(Toolbar.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.<init> + 3(Toolbar.java:3)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance + 417(Constructor.java:417)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView + 594(LayoutInflater.java:594)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag + 696(LayoutInflater.java:696)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate + 755(LayoutInflater.java:755)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate + 758(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate + 492(LayoutInflater.java:492)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate + 397(LayoutInflater.java:397)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate + 353(LayoutInflater.java:353)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor + 1(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.checkCloseActionMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java)
       at com.peter.trainer.Preferences.<init>(Preferences.java)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate + 5133(Activity.java:5133)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate + 1087(Instrumentation.java:1087)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity + 2175(ActivityThread.java:2175)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity + 2261(ActivityThread.java:2261)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600 + 141(ActivityThread.java:141)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1256(ActivityThread.java:1256)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 99(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 137(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 5103(ActivityThread.java:5103)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke + 525(Method.java:525)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 737(ZygoteInit.java:737)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 553(ZygoteInit.java:553)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

After checking the generated IDs as suggested the file is:
abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark which is part of  android.support.design.R.drawable . So is this an error in the google support libraries?

Comment: You can start by looking at which resource has that particular resource id in the generated files.

Answer (score 2):

Do check where you have placed your drawable. If it has been placed in a version-specific folder like drawable-21 then move it to the drawable folder

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, resource IDs doesn't regenerate properly on build. This happens mostly when we are trying to set a resource as an `int` value.

For example this `ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.your_image)` can cause `Resources$NotFoundException` on some phones so I had to catch it like below:

```js
try {
  mImage.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.your_image));
} catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
  mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);
}
```

Catching Exceptions isn't the answer obviously, this is a build problem and more investigations are needed to find the exact cause.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the generated ids. The referenced ID points to abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark which is part of android.support.design.R.drawable. So this should be a support lib error?

Comment: yes, i have already tried many answers. for all i've seen so far, it's very much possible that it's a bug in gradle or somewhere in libraries. this issue was seen in Eclipse bulds too. so, try updating all libraries & sdk packages & then clean & rebuild the project again. Also, feel free to let me know if you solved the issue. I'm curuios to know

Comment: Unfortunately the error persists even after updating the libraries. The only phone which triggers that exception is the motorla defy mini. I don't really know how I can stop that from happening

Comment: can you give me the link to your app? by testing it in a few phones I may be able to get an idea for a solution. this problem happens on api lower than 20 and I kinda resolved it by removing the image view for kitkat all together